# Sampling a very large dataset in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a very big dataset (around 40 million rows) and I am trying to take a stratified sample of it across two classes (from the column class).

I already had to union all the different tables across each month and had to expand row counts into repeated rows (as such I don't have a unique identifier per row).

I tried the following method but it's taking forever:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT *, 
             row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY subquery.class ORDER BY uuid_generate_v1()) AS sequence 
     FROM (SELECT * FROM all_tables) 
          AS subquery)
     AS sub2
WHERE sub2.sequence <= 10
```

I am using PostgreSQL 12.1.

Thanks in advance!!

** Edit **

Sorry I didn't explicitly ask:
What would you recommend for extracting a stratified random sample from the dataset that wouldn't take forever to run?

Comment: What actually is the question ?

Comment: I am not sure either, but it looks like you are looking for the `TABLESAMPLE` clause of `SELECT`.

Comment: Thank you for the comment: I updated the question as it was unclear! I tried TABLESAMPLE but I am not sure how to use it and get an equal number of observations on the two classes I am looking at?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `TABLESAMPLE` as suggested by @Laurenz Albe in the comments.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
         SELECT *, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY subquery.class ORDER BY uuid_generate_v1()) AS sequence
         FROM (
                  SELECT *
                  FROM all_tables TABLESAMPLE system(5) -- how much % from the rows to return
              ) AS subquery
     )
         AS sub2
WHERE sub2.sequence <= 10
```

There are two sampling methods: `system` and `bernoulli` - you can read more about them here: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/TABLESAMPLE_Implementation

On my machine your query runs for 1min 30sec for 30 million rows and with tablesmaple of 5% it takes only 5 seconds

PS: UUID v1 are time based, so they are kind of sorted :) so I guess you want to `ORDER BY random()` instead